# Why should I use the HttpClient in an integration test when the HttpServer seems enough

Tags: asp.net-web-api, integration-testing

What I basically do in a Web API integration test is just using the HttpServer and this seems enough because my Web API controllers action is triggered through the request.

```
var _server = new HttpServer(config);
var _invoker = new HttpMessageInvoker(_server);
var response =_invoker.SendAsync(request, new CancellationToken()).Result;
```

Why do I still see so many people creating a HttpClient like:

```
using(var client = new HttpClient(server))
{
    var response = client.SendAsync(request,...);
}
```

What is the better reason to use the HttpClient to do a request?

In my opinion when I want to test how my code behaves with the Web API pipeline for me the HttpServer seems fine at least the same pipeline is processed using the HttpServer alone or with the HttpClient.

What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what happens is that `HttpClient` extends `HttpMessageInvoker` and adds extra functionalities...basically it is a richer object. If you need to perform various http-related operations it'd be wise to use the `HttpClient` because it already implements many common operations such as `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` requests etc.

By the way, to answer your question, if the `HttpMessageInvoker` and the `HttpServer` are enough for you because they offer the functionalities required to run your integration tests, then there's no actual benefit in choosing one over the other since there is no performance gains whatsoever. Unless, as stated above, your tests required more specific functionality that are implemented by the `HttpMessageInvoker` base class

Comment: Oh yes the HttpMessageInvoker has really only the SendAsync... Whyever... probably tomorrow I would have found that out realizing I can not send data without HttpClient hehe.

Comment: I go one step back and have to ask again because => When using the HttpServer only I know I have no DeleteAsync/PostAsync etc... but I can have an .SendAsync with a request object where I can define the Http method like Delete/Post. Would that not be a replacement? for the HttpClient? So that I start thinking the HttpClient is just a convenient helper?